# 'As a result of' Usage

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrase-usage, modifiers

*As a result of* seems to be quite a versatile phrase, and I can't entirely figure out the contexts in which it is used. This statement is apparently wrong:

> Sound can travel through water for enormous distances, its acoustic energy prevented from being dissipated **as a result of** boundaries in the ocean created by water layers of different temperatures and densities.

However, this statement is apparently correct:

> Sound can travel through water for enormous distances, its acoustic energy prevented from dissipating **by** boundaries in the ocean created by water layers of different temperatures and densities.

The only reason I can think of is because *by* implies the involvement of an agent (a noun), whereas *as a result of* implies a process, action, or event. What is the strict difference between *by* and *as a result of*? In which contexts can *as a result of* be used?

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with the first example, though the second is a bit more idiomatic.